# Contrutor de Queries

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou aprendendo sobre cakephp e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Tenho que fazer a soma de uma coluna na minha tabela (Uso Postgres).

Estou tentando utilizar a função sum() do próprio cake.

Meu controller

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

public function index()
{
   $contratacoes = TableRegistry::get('Contratacoes');
   $query = $contratacoes->find();
   $soma_financiamento = $query->select(['sum'   
    =>$query->func()->sum('vlr_financiamento')]);
   $this->set(['soma_financiamento' => $soma_financiamento]);
}
```

Minha view, somente para testar

```
<?= $soma_financiamento; ?>
```

Só que está saindo isso:

```
SELECT (SUM(vlr_financiamento)) AS "sum" FROM contratacoes Contratacoes
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *Query Builder* do CakePHP funciona basicamente em dois passos. O primeiro passo você monta a *query*, no segundo passo você executa a *query* e ela pode lhe retornar um objeto da sua *entity* ou uma *collection*.

No exemplo que você apresentou, você está executando apenas o primeiro passo, que é montar a query. Quando você dá um `echo` na sua *view*, ele está excutando o método `toString` do *Query Builder*, e não executando a query que ele montou.

Para executar a query e retorna um objeto com os dados do seu banco de dados, você pode usar um dos seguintes métodos: `all()`, `toArray()`, `first()`, `extract()` e para métodos que façam `insert`, `delete` ou `update` o método `execute()`. Recomendo que teste-os para ver o funcionamento e seu comportamento.

No seu caso, você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

public function index()
{
   $contratacoes = TableRegistry::get('Contratacoes');
   $query = $contratacoes->find();
   $soma_financiamento = $query
      ->select(['sum' =>$query->func()->sum('vlr_financiamento')])
      ->first();

   // Descomente a linha abaixo para ver o resultado da query
   // debug($soma_financiamento);

   $this->set(['soma_financiamento' => $soma_financiamento->sum]);
}
```

Existe outras maneiras de fazer isso. O *Query Builder* armazena internamente uma *colletion* com os dados da sua *query*. Ela é populada quando é chamado um método da *colletion* com o estado atual do seu *Query Builder*.

Sendo assim outra possível solução é:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

public function index()
{
   $contratacoes = TableRegistry::get('Contratacoes');
   $query = $contratacoes->find();

   $this->set(['soma_financiamento' => $query->sumOf('vlr_financiamento')]);
}
```

Referencias e leitura recomendada da documentaçãodo CakePHP:

- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#aggregation